# Kafka "num.partitions" setting in service.properties does not take effect

Tags: apache-kafka

We use Kafka in Docker container. We create topics automatically if the topic does not exist when producing or consuming messages. We want 3 partitions for the topics, so set

```
num.partitions=3
```

in file /etc/kafka/server.properties in the Kafka container. However, it does not take effect. After doing the setting and restarting the container, then try subscribing or publishing on some non-existential topics, the topics are created, but only with one partition.

We tried this on containers created from image confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0 and also on containers created from image confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.1, and the behaviors were the same.

We tested creating topics with command:

```
kafka-topics --create --topic my_topic --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3
```

This correctly created the topic with three partitions. But we need Kafka to create multi-partition topics automatically.

What could cause the problem? Or how to make Kafka auto-create multi-partition topics?

We do not have any dynamic configs. This is verified by running the following commands:

```
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-default --describe
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 0 (or other ids) --describe
```

Those commands return empty results.

Comment: What docker container for Kafka do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer comes kinda late, but I've been struggling with the same thing using the docker image: *confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.4*.

The solution for me was adding a new environment variable in my docker-compose:
**KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3** (or the partitions you want)

This will automatically add the property *num.partitions* in your *kafka.properties* file under /etc/kafka/ directory.

Modifying the property *num.partitions* in /etc/kafka/server.properties didn't work for me neither.

Comment: Marking as answer. In case this is helpful, this document explains the name prefixing rules for the docker container environment variables: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-enterprise-ak-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers are ephemeral, meaning that once you stopped them, all those changes that you've applied are lost.

If you want to overwrite the default settings you have to mount the property file:

1. Create a server.properties file on your machine
2. Fill it in with the properties that you need ( including the original ones )
3. Mount this file and in order to replace the original one from the container:

```
docker run ... -v /path/to/custom/server.properties:/etc/kafka/server.properties ...
```